# Scala RestAPI Client design : handling exceptions

Tags: scala

I am from Java background and I am trying to understand how to design Rest API Client methods.

Client is synchronous and most of the methods invokes Rest GET interfaces to retrieve some entities.

From my understanding:

1. If I get 200 from the RetAPI, I return the entity wrapped in an Some
2. If I get 404 from the RestAPI, I return None
3. If I get 500 status codes or any other IOExceptions,I wrap them in an MyClientException and throw

Does this API design follow Scala best practises ?

```
class MyClient(baseUrl: String) {


    @throws(classOf[MyClientException])
    def getDataSet(dataSetId: String) : Option[DataSet] = {
      //if 200 , return Some[dataSet]
      //if 404, return None
      //if 500 or network errors,throw MyClientException
    }
}
```

Comment: This is mainly opinion. But, usually you should not throw exceptions that you want to handle. Thus, instead of an `Option` I would use a `Try` or a `Either` _(I personally prefer Either)_. Then, I would make `MyClientException` a **sealed trait** with two sub **case classes**, `NotFound` _(for 404)_ & `NetworkError` _(for 500)_.

Comment: I would only add to @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez's comment by saying that you might want to wrap the result in a Future, since it is very likely that these calls will be asynchronous. So therefore your result type would be:
`Future[Either[MyClientException, DataSet]]`

Comment: @ReganKoopmans `Future` already holds an exception if there is an error, so better to just use `Future[DataSet]` and let `Future` handle all the exceptions in a consistent way. You can `match` the `Throwable` to find which specific problem caused the error.

Comment: For 1 I think you mean `Some` instead of `Option` and for 2 I think you mean `None` instead of `Option[None]`. I know this can be subtle but it's better to directly underline what can bring confusion in the future to newcomers.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez something like follows ?
   //if status 200  Success(entity)
   //if status 404 Failure(NotFound())
   //others Failure(NetworkError())

Comment: Also, if it's a public api, you really don't need to share that an Exception has occurred, do you?

Comment: @AshikaUmanga yes, that is one option. Tim's answer provides another good alternative. Anyways, in general the important rule is to have a convention across all your code base. And usually, you won't be throwing checked exceptions but rather wrapping them on some data structure. Finally, if you use future _(which you probably are)_ then the best is to let the internals of the future handle the errors.

Answer (score 4):

This is very much a matter of opinion, but I would use exceptions for all error cases. You can define your own HTTP exceptions:

```
case class MyHttpException(code: StatusCode) extends Throwable
```

If your client is synchronous then return `Try` but typically a REST client is asynchronous, in which case you return `Future`. Both of these object track exceptions and make the `Throwable` available in the case of error.

Answer (score 1):

I've written some Scala Apis before for things like this and I tend to use the type Either to differentiate between errors and success like this, rather than do the Java-esc thing of throwing exceptions.

```
case class MyClientError(errorMessage :String)

class MyClient(baseUrl: String) {

def getDataSet(dataSetId: String) : Either[MyClientError,DataSet] = {
  call(dataSetId) match {
     case dataset if result.status == HTTP_OK => Right(dataset)
     case _ if result.status == HTTP_404 => Left(MyClientException("Not found"))
     case result => Left(MyClientException(s"Got non 200 response: ${result.status}")
    }
  }
}
```

This way the caller can do this:

```
getDataSet(54) match {
   case Left(err) => println(s"got an error ${err.errorMessage}")
   case Right(dataset) => println("got a good answer!")
}
```

Either tends to compose quite well, can be used in for-yield blocks, is rich in terms of returning a reason for a failure etc. It's easy to turn List(ids) -> Either[List[errors], List[datasets]] etc.

--

How you handle exceptions on failures is a slightly wider question. Ultimately up to the system designer. You could return the error, put it aside and move on or implement retry logic. Of course, it depends what call() returns when an error occurs. This example demonstrates how you could retry if call() returns a Future that fails with a throwable:

```
def getDataSet(dataSetId: String, retries :Int = 3) : Future[Either[MyClientError,DataSet]] = {
  call(dataSetId).flatMap {
     case Success(dataset) if result.status == HTTP_OK => Future.successful(Right(dataset))
     case Success(_) if result.status == HTTP_404 => Future.successful(Left(MyClientException("Not found")))
     case Failure(exc) if thr.isTransientError && retries > 0 => getDataSet(dataSetId, retries - 1)
     case Failure(exc) if thr.isTransientError && retries == 0 => Future.successful(Left(MyClientException(s"Tried 3 times but failed: ${exc.getMessage}")))
     case Failure(exc) => Future.successful(Left(MyClientException(s"Unrecoverable: ${exc.getMessage}")))
     case Success(result) => Future.successful(Left(MyClientException(s"Got non 200 response: ${result.status}")))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens when there is a network error or other exception inside `call`?

Comment: I've added a final paragraph to answer that question @Tim